# Flutter fullscreen: system_chrome.dart Error

Tags: flutter, debugging, flutter-layout

I am working on my flutter application and I want to display it in fullscreen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I`m using SystemChrome in the main.dart file but when I debug my code the file "system_chrome.dart" gets opened with this error:

```
    } else {
      assert(mode == SystemUiMode.manual && overlays != null);
      await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>(
        'SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays',
        _stringify(overlays!),
      );
    }
```

If I use SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []); in each build method of my pages individually the code gets debugged without a problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it too early - before Flutter framework is up.

You can call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` to get Flutter framework up and running, before calling your method.

Basically, change your `main()` to this:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // add this line
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```